# How to scroll to a particular location initially on the basis of id?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-ios

I am using scrollTo to let scrollview element scroll to a particular id as follows:

```
let scrollviewRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    selectedid && selectedid!=null && selectedid!=undefined &&
    scrollviewRef.current?.scrollTo({
      y:selectedid,
      animated:true,
    })

    getData();
    
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonOnnclick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        handleBackButtonOnnclick,
      );
    };
  }, [changedstatus]);
<ScrollView ref={scrollviewRef}>
          {data != '' &&
            data !== undefined &&
            data !== null &&
            data.map((item) => {
              const selected = item.vaccine_list
                .map((a) => a.vaccineInternalId)
                .includes(selectedid);
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={item.id}
                  style={{
                    paddingLeft: 10,
                    paddingRight: 10,
                  }}
                  onPress={() => handleOnPress(item.id, item)}>
                  {expand[item.id] ? (
                    <ExpandedVaccineComponent
                      item={item}
                      id={id}
                      navigation={navigation}
                      changevaccinestatus={changevaccinestatus}
                      childdob={childdob}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <NotExpandedVaccineComponent item={item} />
                  )}
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
        </ScrollView>
```

But when I execute this, it is not initially scrolling to the selectedid, could anyone tell me what have I missed out here?
Any leads would be great.
Let me know if anything else is required for better clarity.

Comment: Have you tried `scrollviewRef.current?.scrollIntoView()`?

Comment: scrollIntoView() is this included in ScrollView props? @ShriharshaKL